# angular js search using filter keyword to display array items grouped by headers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, search, filter, keyword-search

I am trying to display results from an array :--

```
$scope.headerValue1 =[{title:"Source",list:[]},{title:"Target",list:[]},{title:"Local Variables",list:[]},{title:"Constants",list:[]}];
```

inside my search bar using *li and ng-repeat* tags (one for displaying the title and then followed by one for listing each items for that title) using **filter:model name of search textbox**.
There is a search box to search for the list items.I want to :-

- Display the list items based on the search keyword so that the header title corresponding to that list item is also displayed.
- Display all the list items if user is typing a particular title in the search box.

I am giving the code below :-

```
var inputString = '<span class="btn-group searchable-dropdown" data-ng-show=" true">'

+ '<button class="btn btn-sm btn-default btn-block dropdown-toggle"'
// +'data-ng-disabled="false"
// '
+ 'data-toggle="dropdown">'
+ '<span data-ng-if="true" class="ng-binding ng-scope"  >'
+ '{{curr_rules['
+ idx
+ '].rhs.args['
+ i
+ '].selectedVal}}'
+ '</span>'
// +'<!--
// end
// ngIf:
// !ruleDefinitionArgs.selectArgValue
// -->
// '
+ '<span class="caret"></span>'
+ '</button>'

+ '<ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" >'

+ '<li>'
+ '<div class="dropdown-header">'
+ '<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" style="width: 50%;" data-ng-click="searchBox($event);"'
// +'data-ng-model="ruleDefinition.columnFilter"
// '
+ 'data-ng-model="curr_rules['
+ idx
+ '].rhs.args['
+ i
+ '].searchField"/> '
+ '<button style="margin-left: 5px" ng-click="addConstant(curr_rules['
+ idx
+ '].rhs.args['
+ i
+ '].searchField,$event)" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Add Constant</button>'
+ '</div>'
+ '</li>'
+ '<li class="divider"></li>'

+ '<li data-ng-repeat="headeritem in headerValue1 | filter:curr_rules['
+ idx
+ '].rhs.args['
+ i
+ '].searchField" data-ng-if="headeritem.list.length>0" ><span class="list-head"><b>{{headeritem.title}}</b></span>'
+ '<ul class="search-list-dropdown">'
+ '<li  data-ng-repeat="item in headeritem.list| filter:curr_rules['
+ idx
+ '].rhs.args['
+ i
+ '].searchField : startsWith" data-ng-click="populateValSource(curr_rules,'
+ idx
+ ','
+ i
+ ',item,headeritem.title);"'
+ 'data-ng-value=item'
+ '>'
+ '<a href="javascript:void(0)">{{item}}</a>'
+ '</li>'
+ '</ul>'
+ '</li>'

+ '</ul>'

+ '</span>');

 var input = angular.element(inputString);
```

I am trying to implement a searchable dropdown by dynamically appending this element inside which there is the search textbox and below it is data displayed within ul/li tags. 
I have tried filter keyword ,but it does not serve both the purpose mentioned at the same time.
Need help,Thanks

Comment: Can you post your code or create a plunkr ?

Comment: Edited my question and added code

Comment: @suzo  Edited my question and added code.

Comment: What is `curr_rules` ? Can you replicate this in a plunkr ?

Comment: @suzo It is part of the ng-model of the search textbox.We can replace it with anything simple like "searchField" in place of :- curr_rules['+ idx+ '].rhs.args['+ i+ '].searchField in the ng-model and after the filter keywords.Having problems replicating in plunkr...still strying.Thanks

Comment: I've made a similar search filter as per your question, please check and let me know if that is what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you've given is not clear, So I've made a simple input search filter below. Check and let me know if that is what you are expecting.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $compile){
  $scope.headerValue1 = [{"title":"Source","list":["attr1","attr2"]},{"title":"Target","list":["newattr2","attr3","testattr3"]},{"title":"Local Variables","list":["l1attr1","l1newattr2","l1attr3"]},{"title":"Constants","list":["c1l1attr1","c3l1attr3","c4l1testatr3"]}];
  
  var inputString = '<input type="text" ng-model="searchText">'
  + '<p>{{searchText}}</p>'
      + '<ul>'
  + '<li ng-repeat="each in headerValue1" ng-show="filtered.length">{{each.title}}'
  + '<ul>'
  + '<li ng-repeat="item in each.list | filter :searchText as filtered">{{item}}</li>'
  + '</ul>'
  + '</li>'
  + '</ul>';
  
  angular.element('#content').append(inputString);
  
 $compile(angular.element('#content').contents())($scope);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div id="content"></div>
  
</body>
```

Comment: Could you please replace  **$scope.headerValue1** with $scope.headerValue1=
[{title:"Source",list:["attr1","attr2"]},
 {title:"Target",list:["newattr2","attr3","testattr3"]},
 {title:"Local Variables",list:["l1attr1","l1newattr2","l1attr3"]},
 {title:"Constants",list:["c1l1attr1","c3l1attr3","c4l1testattr3"]}];
and add 
<li ng-repeat="item in each.list | filter:searchText">{{item }}</li>
  before the last </ul>.

Rest is all right.
I want search with 2 above mentioned features in original post on the title and the list items.
,Thanks.

Comment: Yes this is what i have at present .
Now I want suppose if I type source then all source attribute will be listed below .And also this search is only "pattern wise" ,is it possible to get the search results in "startsWith" type for list items then followed by "pattern wise" type results.

Comment: You have to write a custom filter do such pattern wise filtering. Built in filters cannot give such functionality.

Comment: Please accept the answer, If you think my answer has helped you solve your problem such that we can work on other questions. :)

Comment: Yes,did that. Ok suppose if I type source then all source attribute will be listed below .Right now only source is listing.Can this be done over here or we need custom filters for that also?
Thanks.

Comment: Cool. We can do that here. Just remove the inner filter. Edited my answer. Run it and check.

Comment: Yes but in that case if we search with a particular item which is present in the list,the item along with other things are displayed which has the same pattern.I want if element is found only that will be displayed along with its title above.

Comment: In that case , keep the inner filter and remove the outer filter, such that filtering will be done based on the item and not title

Comment: That is the problem, i want the list item to appear followed by only its title.If I do that all the list titles will be coming.I want both the things.That is the requirement.

Comment: Got your issue, editing my answer. 2mins. Which version of Angular are you using ?

Comment: Check now. That will work only if your Angular version is above 1.3. Let me know if it's below that, I'll provide an alternative.

Comment: I dont think so dude 
If I search by title (eg:-source/target etc) it must display all its respective items only.

Comment: Here the search is based on items inside not the title, if you want both, add filter to both like I did earlier. I'm not getting your exact requirement.

Comment: I want two things:-
1.If search item matches title then list items specific to the title will be displayed along with its title.So if i search with source it will display source and all source list items.
2. If search item matches with a item in list it only will be displayed alongwith its title.
So basically I am trying to filter both title and list items based on searchText,but these two requirements are not fullfilling at the same time.